# Print the key and a subset of fields if a field is not a specific value

Tags: jq

I am new to jq and can't seem to quite get the syntax right for what I want to do.  I am executing a command and piping its JSON output into jq.  The structure looks like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1658186185,
  "nodes": {
    "x3006c0s13b1n0": {
      "Mom": "x3006c0s13b1n0.hsn.cm",
      "Port": 15002,
      "state": "free",
      "pcpus": 64,
      "resources_available": {
        "arch": "linux",
        "gputype": "A100",
        "host": "x3006c0s13b1n0",
        "mem": "527672488kb",
        "ncpus": 64,
        "ngpus": 4,
        "system": "polaris",
        "tier0": "x3006-g1",
        "tier1": "g1",
        "vnode": "x3006c0s13b1n0"
      },
      "resources_assigned": {},
      "comment": "CHC- Offlined due to node health check failure",
      "resv_enable": "True",
      "sharing": "default_shared",
      "license": "l",
      "last_state_change_time": 1658175652,
      "last_used_time": 1658175652
    },
```

And so on with a record for each node. In psuedocode, what I want to do is this:

`if state is not free then display nodename : {comment = "Why is the node down"}`

The nodename is the key, but could be extracted from a field inside the record. However, for future reference, I would like to understand how to get the key.  I figured out (I think) that you can't use == on strings, but instead have to use the regex functions.

This gives me the `if state is not free` part:

`<stdin> |  jq '.nodes[] | .state | test("free") | not'`

This gives me an object with the Mom (which includes the key) and the comment:

`jq '.nodes[] | {Mom: .Mom, comment: .comment}'`

The question is how do I put all that together?  And as for the keys, this gives me a list of the keys: `jq '.nodes | keys'` but that uses the non-array version of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way without touching the keys would be to only `select` those array items that match the condition, and map the remaining items' value to the comment itself using `map_values`:

```bash
jq '.nodes | map_values(select(.state != "free").comment)'
```

```json
{
  "x3006c0s13b1n0": "CHC- Offlined due to node health check failure"
}
```

Keeping the whole `comments` object, which is closer to your desired output, would be similar:

```bash
jq '.nodes | map_values(select(.state != "free") | {comment})'
```

```json
{
  "x3006c0s13b1n0": {
    "comment": "CHC- Offlined due to node health check failure"
  }
}
```

Accessing the keys directly is still possible though. You may want to have a look at [keys, keys_unsorted](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#keys,keys_unsorted) or [to_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries).

Comment: Your first one is perfect.  I didn't realize it would automatically prefix it with the key.  That is nice and succinct and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!